# Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC '

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I'm having a serious issue with causing validation within one of my searchBar TextBox's within my C# application.

Every time i run the program and enter text, number or even certain special characters i am facing no issues... However, the second i use a quotation mark (') i am presented with an error as found in the title.

Below is the code i am using upon performing a specific process, please can someone save me:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(
     "SET ROWCOUNT 25 
     select ui.USERID [User ID], 
            ui.BADGENUMBER [Employee No.], 
            ui.NAME [Name], 
            ci.CHECKTIME [Clock Time], 
            ci.CHECKTYPE [I/O], 
            ci.SENSORID [Sensor ID] 
     FROM 
            USERINFO ui, 
            CHECKINOUT ci 
     WHERE 
            ui.USERID = ci.USERID and 
            ci.CHECKTYPE in ('I','O') and 
            ui.NAME like '%" + searchBar.Text + "%' 
     ORDER BY 
            CHECKTIME DESC ", con);
```

Thanks in advance people...

Comment: Never, ever, concatenate user input to create SQL. Please search "Bobby Tables". You should be using a *parameter*, i.e. `... ui.NAME like '%' + @name + '%' ORDER BY ...`, where `@name` is a parameter that is given the value from `searchBar.Text`. If most of your data access looks like this, then you need to stop **right now** and revisit your entire data access layer: it is dangerously broken.

Comment: @mrBrown if you are not using like this because there may be chance of SQL Injection .

Comment: @DhavalPatel I would say that there is a certainty of it ;p

Comment: I'm looking into parameters as we speak, I'm still learning on how to create and make use of clean code so thanks for both the criticism and the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `'` in SQL - `''`.  Here's an example of how you could do this, with parameters.

```
string SQL = "SET ROWCOUNT 25 select ui.USERID [User ID], ui.BADGENUMBER [Employee No.], ui.NAME [Name], ci.CHECKTIME [Clock Time], ci.CHECKTYPE [I/O], ci.SENSORID [Sensor ID] FROM USERINFO ui, CHECKINOUT ci WHERE ui.USERID = ci.USERID and ci.CHECKTYPE in ('I','O') and ui.NAME like @SearchText ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC ";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchText", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + searchBar.Text + "%";

SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

This will both parameterize your query and escape any single quotes you have in the search text.

Comment: God bless you Sir, absolute life saver!

Comment: I'm learning about parameters now as I need to implement this method of searching a database using clean code throughout many of my forms.

Comment: If you using a parameter, it is **incorrect** to do the `searchBar.Text.Replace("'", "''")` bit - it should be **just** `.Value = "%" + searchBar.Text + "%";`

Comment: @MarcGravell - I didn't know that.  I corrected the answer.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can not use ' Unfortunately, when you run the query, SQL will interpret the single quote inside the string as signifying the end of that string.